# Image not upload successfully in mvc 5

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upload images in MVC 5 but image not post to server side and

**HTML Code is**

below code is under form tag

```
<form action="~/Uerprofile/UploadPhotos" method="post" >
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-grou">
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 form-group">
   <label class="label lbldesign">Upload Your Photos</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="pphoto" name="pphoto" autofocus accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg" />
                   <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Upload" />

                    </div>

                </div>
```

```
public ActionResult Uploadphotos(HttpPostedFileBase pphoto)
{
        pphoto = Request.Files["pphoto"];

        if (pphoto != null)
        {
            try
            {
                DataModel dm = new DataModel();
                dm.Photo = converttobyte(pphoto);
                TempData["error"] = "Photo Upload Successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TempData["error"] = ex.Message;
                RedirectToAction("EditProfile", "UserProfile");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("EditProfile", "UserProfile");
        }   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `FORM` tag?

Comment: That can't possibly be your action code, it won't even compile.

Comment: Is "Uerprofile" correct? That looks like a typo. Also you have no closing `form` tag. Please be extra careful to ensure you're giving us all the information, otherwise we can't really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your `<form>` as the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" if you want to populate `Request.Files`

Using HTML helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName",
                "ControllerName",
                FormMethod.Post,
                new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

If you are not using HTML Helper then add the attribute to your form tag.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/SomeUrl">
```

Comment: but i am not use html helper

Comment: I see you are new. Please take a second to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. You can mark this answer as correct so others with the same issue know the resolution and say thanks by up voting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will be helpful

My View Code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ImportData", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div class="row">
        <div id="radio" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="file" id="dataFile" name="upload" class="btn btn-info" />
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div id="radio" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">
            <div class="input-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload Your file");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: <form action="~/Uerprofile/UploadPhotos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has no `<form>` tag, which is what tells the browser how to handle the clicking of the submit button.